# Converting urls to links in a string using preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to convert urls to links in a string

I have the following string :

```
$x="Welcome to my [homepage](http://example.com) ,Please check our [About us](http://example.com/about-us) page for more info about this site.
```

I want to convert everything inside [ and ] to link title and everything inside ( and ) to value of href attribute:

Welcome to my [homepage](http://example.com) ,Please check our [About us](http://example.com/about-us) page for more info about this site.

I tried **preg_replace()** function, but it doesn't work

```
$x="Welcome to my [homepage](http://example.com) ,Please check our [About us](http://example.com/about-us) page for more info about this site";

echo preg_replace("/\[([^\]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/i","<a href='$2'>$1</a>",$x);
```

I am getting the same string in output :

```
Welcome to my [homepage](http://example.com) ,Please check our [About us](http://example.com/about-us) page for more info about this site.
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Please help!

Comment: Your input string looks like markdown. Have you considered using a markdown parser instead? (I guess it would be kind of overkill if this is the only thing you would be using it for, but still thought it worth suggesting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex like as

```
echo preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/","<a href='$2'>$1</a>",$x);
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/mZ6kJ7/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
$x = str_replace("[homepage]", "<a href='www.example.com/homepage'>homepage</a>", $x);
```